# select in linq and access to element

Tags: c#, linq

i have a select in `linq`:

in if i must compare username and password for permitted,but a cant access to element of user.

```
   var user = from u in db.tbl_User select new {u.UserName,u.Password};
 if(txtname == user && txtpass == pass)
            {
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            Visible = false;
            frm.Show();

            }
            else
            {

               MessageBox.Show("Error","UserName or Password is wrong",MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            }
```

how can i give element of `user`?

Comment: salam, farsi mizari inja pesar jan? doros bepors soaleto ta javab begiri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `user` variable is a query which returns a *sequence* of matching users - not a *single* user.

It sounds like you might want:

```
var user = db.tbl_User
             .FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == txtname.Text
                                  && u.Password == txtPass.Text);
if (user != null)
{
    ...
}
```

(I hope you don't *really* have plain-text passwords, by the way...)

Comment: i try that but i have an error: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'

Comment: replace `txtname` with `txtname.Text`

Comment: and replace `txtPass` with `txtPass.Text`

Comment: @HamedRahmani: I've edited my post - but it would have helped if you'd explained the types of your variables to start with. I don't know how you'd expect us to know that `txtname` was a `TextBox`, not a string, given that you appeared to be trying to compare it with a string...

Answer (score 0):

```
var user = from u in db.tbl_User select new {u.UserName,u.Password};
if(user.Count() != 1)
    return;
if(txtname == user.UserName && txtpass == pass.Password)
{
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        Visible = false;
        frm.Show();

        }
        else
        {

           MessageBox.Show("Error","UserName or Password is wrong" ,MessageBoxButtons.OK);

}
```

Comment: age javabeto gerefti feleshe bala ro bezan va bad ham javab ro tayid kon.

Comment: i cant access to user.UserName

Comment: because user is a query, you can use it like:  user.single<User>().UserName ... where User is your table

Comment: mishe id yahoo ya gmail shomaro dashte basham?

Comment: 09355351325 m.tahsildari@gmail.com